# Versioning of code and data in Oracle

Tags: oracle, schema, database-schema, versioning, snapshot

Let's imagine a standard situation.

Having the current DB schema in a working state, I would like to create a snapshot of this state of schema objects, name it `SNAP_1`.

Then if updated schema and got problems (bugs or unstable work of new code) it would be good to switch quickly - in one command - the whole schema code back to `SNAP_1`.

I'm wondering is there any built-in feature of Oracle DBMS for versioning:

- PL/SQL code (schema objects)
- Data (for example, within configuration tables)

**Does Oracle DBMS give native tools for versioning at least one of these two?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no. But Oracle 11.2+  has something called "Editions".
This method has many restrictions. For example, data and table structure cannot be versioned.
Cool thing is that separate sessions can use a different version of the DB objects simultaneously. (package before fix and after fix)
Here is oracle's documentation.[EDITION](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_5009.htm#SQLRF20017)  and
[Examples of editions](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/edition-based-redefinition-11gr2)

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for. But I could not google it, because for request "Oracle Editions" I got results on description for editions of DBMS: mainly XE. So I started to think that I've imagined this )))